# Range Query - Tree does not contain upper and/or lower bound

Tags: algorithm, range, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have a `Binary Search Tree`

```
        50
     /       \
    17        72
  /    \     /   \
 12    23   54   76
 /\    /     \
9 14  19     67
```

Sorry, I suck at drawing trees

I want to return all nodes that fall within a certain range. For example

```
[12, 23] --> {12, 14, 17, 23, 19}
```

My approach is simple

1. Find LCA
2. Find lower bound
3. While node != LCA.parent, add right subtree
4. From LCA, while node != upper bound, add left subtree
5. Add upper bound and left subtree of upper bound

However, what if one, or both, of the bounds is NOT contained in the tree. For example

```
[11, 72] --> {12, 14, 17, 23, 19, 50, 54, 67, 72}
```

My approach seems similar except instead of searching for bounds, search until your bound is exceeded by the nodes child. So after finding the "LCA" (not a true LCA since it doesn't exist), look for 11. After arriving at 12, see that left child is less than 11 so stop there.

1. Is there a more efficient solution for performing this range query? BST is not mandatory, it just seemed like a good data structure to use.
2. Will my approach work/ is it efficient for when the bounds are not contained in the tree?

Comment: Why do you care about LCA? Just start at the root and recursively traverse the subtrees that might contain relevant entries.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Very good point. You've also helped me see a flaw in my implementation. If I am looking for [10, 23] and 9 has a right child of 11, my implementation will fail. Thanks.

Comment: So is this question solved?

Comment: @Nico Yes, its solved

Comment: Great. Then either post an answer and accept it or delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nico suggests, you just need a recursive algorithm to traverse the tree, you don't need to care about LCA. The fact that the binary tree is a binary search tree, allows you to perform some optimizations and avoid traversing the whole tree. eg: don't traverse the left branch of a node, if the value of the node is lower than your lower bound.

```cs
void FindNodesInBound(BSTNode node, int lowerBound, int upperBound, List<int> matches) {
    if (node != null) {
        if (node.Value >= lowerBound)
            FindNodesInBound(node.Left, lowerBound, upperBound, matches);
        if (node.Value >= lowerBound && node.Value <= upperBound)
            matches.Add(node.Value);
        if (node.Value <= upperBound)
            FindNodesInBound(node.Right, lowerBound, upperBound, matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Following @Nico's comment, this was the implementation I was coding. I implemented in `golang` which made adding to a passed in `slice` parameter a little more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

- "find" the lower value (12 in example). It returns a data structure which allows inorder walk, such as a `std::map::iterator` in C++. In simple terms, it is the path from root to the searched node.
- start inorder walk from the found node until the higher value (23 in example) is reached.

---

Since the question says, "BST is not mandatory, it just seemed like a good data structure to use.", another option is to keep the numbers in a sorted array. This of course limits the option of modifying the set of numbers. In the sorted array, binary search for the lower number and start walking towards the higher end (same as the BST approach.)

Comment: good idea to use in-order traversal after finding the lower bound